# Indentation inside of <?php tag with PHP Code Sniffer

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

Within our PHP project, our internal standard is to have all code inside of PHP indented by two spaces. Example:

```
<?php

   class Foo
   {
     ...
```

I must be confused on how to configure that, as I always receive an error that the the file has "2 spaces, expected 0" in the indent. How do I appropriately configure that?

Comment: You can configure how many spaces each indent level should be, but you can't configure PHPCS to force you to indent top-level code like that. It assumes that all code begins at the 0 column.

Answer (score -1):

**You might use `PhpCsFixer\Fixer\PhpTag\BlankLineAfterOpeningTagFixer` class** from [PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer).

If you are new to the tool and you want to make it really easy to start, the best is to use it with [EasyCodingStandard](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/03/combine-power-of-php-code-sniffer-and-php-cs-fixer-in-3-lines/) like this:

```
# easy-coding-standard.neon
checkers:
    - PhpCsFixer\Fixer\PhpTag\BlankLineAfterOpeningTagFixer
```

Install it:

```
composer require --dev symplify\easy-coding-standard
```

Run it:

```
vendor/bin/ecs check src
```

Fix it:

```
vendor/bin/ecs check src --fix
```

**Enjoy and let me know how it works for you.**

If any troubles come up, just [create an issue here](https://github.com/Symplify/Symplify/issues). I'm happy to improve this tool as much as possible.

Comment: How does this answer his question?